# CSS .cur cursor format

Tags: css, cursor

I set custom cursor `url(mouse2.cur)` and it doesnt change.

`(mouse2.png)` works perfectly! Whats the problem ?

```
body{
    cursor: url(mouse2.cur),pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: What size of the cursor in pixels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different browsers have different support in url of the cursors.

> Firefox/Mac, Safari/Mac, Chrome/Mac don't support PNG and JPG cursors (tested with 48px cursors). 
>   IE only supports cursors in the CUR format.
>
> According to CanIUse: http://caniuse.com/#search=cursor

W3C CSS3 Specification states:

> The UA must support the following image file formats:
>
> - PNG, as defined in [PNG]
> - SVG, as defined in [SVG], in secure static    mode [SVG-INTEGRATION]
> - any other non-animated image file format that    they support for  in other properties, such as the the    background-image
>     property

By the way, W3C CSS3 Specification says that `.cur` cursors should be supported by most browsers.

> Note: At the time of writing this specification (spring 2015), the
>   only file formats supported for cursors in common desktop browsers are
>   the .ico and .cur file formats, as designed by Microsoft. For
>   compatibility with legacy content, UAs are encouraged to support
>   these, even though the lack of an open specification makes it
>   impossible to have a normative requirement about these formats. Some
>   information on these formats can be found on Wikipedia.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#cursor

Finally, your `.cur` file may be broken or even link to it returns 404 error. Please check the link to your `.cur` file.

Comment: Just want to note that if you want to use a cursor that inverts, that functionality is not supported by chrome and firefox and will display a black square in place of the .CUR file. =(