# CSS Change Each Cursor

Tags: css

I have a website I'm building and I want to have a custom cursors specified for each property like hand, wait, pointer, default, move and so on...
I'm build an operating system website so I want to have custom cursors.
Here is the CSS code.

```
* {
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/pointer.png"),pointer;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/hand.cur"),hand;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/pointer.cur"),default;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/move.cur"),move;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/move.cur"),all-scroll;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/horizontal-resize.cur"),col-resize;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/horizontal-resize.cur"),e-resize;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/horizontal-resize.cur"),w-resize;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/vertical-resize.cur"),row-resize;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/vertical-resize.cur"),n-resize;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/vertical-resize.cur"),s-resize;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/diagonal-resize-1.cur"),se-resize;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/diagonal-resize-1.cur"),nw-resize;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/diagonal-resize-2.cur"),sw-resize;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/diagonal-resize-2.cur"),ne-resize;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/move.cur"),grab;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/move.cur"),grabbing;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/unavailable.cur"),no-drop;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/unavailable.cur"),not-allowed;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/text.cur"),vertical-text;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/text.png"),text;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/wait.cur"),wait;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/help.cur"),help;
        cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/precision-select.cur"),crosshair;
}
```

The only cursor that happens to load is the one at the bottom (crosshair)
I've also specified some PNG cursors aswell and they did not change the outcome.

I tried putting this into html,body{} and div{} but again nothing worked.
I want something like on [Windows93](https://windows93.net) but without JavaScript
If there is no CSS-only method then I can accept JavaScript ones. But please only vanilla-js.
Thanks!

Comment: Each call to ```cursor: url...``` is overwriting the previous one.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi Weird. I thought adding pointer, hand, etc. at the end would impact those instead?

Comment: all of them should be inside the same cursor : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#Formal_syntax

Comment: Do I specify it like this: cursor:url('pointer.cur') url('hand.cur'), pointer hand; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cursor` values are overwriting each other. This means that the last value is the only one that works, as it is the last one to overwrite the cursor value.

The word that follows the URL is a fallback keyword. This means that if the image cannot be found or rendered, the cursor specified by the keyword will be drawn.

For example, with the property `cursor: url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/precision-select.cur"), crosshair;`, the browser will attempt to draw the cursor specified in the URL, but if it cannot it will use the default `crosshair` cursor.

To get the browser to display different cursors you will need to specify the cursor for each element. For your default cursor you would have:

```
* {
    cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/pointer.cur"),default;
}
```

To get a pointer over links you might then do:

```
a {
    cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/pointer.png"),pointer;
}
```

For crosshairs on a particular element you might try:

```
.target-element {
    cursor:url("../.drive/system/visual/cursors/precision-select.cur"),crosshair;
}
```

You need to specify the cursor property for each element that you wish to have a changed/custom cursor. Using a universal selector for the default cursor ensures that you only specify the property for elements that require it.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I ended up doing and seems to work just fine. The way I expected it to :D

Comment: Also note **.cur** is not well supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037763/css-cur-cursor-format